# Presentation-> Details is disabled on custom role

Tags: presentation, security, role-management

My custom role contains following roles - `Sitecore\Designer` & `Sitecore\Author`

Also I tried giving `Read/Write` access to below items in core database

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Layout

/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Layout/Details
```

but still, it is disabled.

Comment: Are you able to edit the basic fields of the item? I just tested this on one of our systems. I added a custom role that has those two roles added (designer and author), then created a user belonging to this role only. I was able to access the presentation details tab. One thing to note, if the page has a workflow, you need workflow write permission. Once checked out you should be able to see the tab.

Comment: Sitecore role can override other roles. You need to make sure that when setting the read and write access, there are no other roles which are overriding it.

Comment: I have the same issue after I installed the KB1001328(https://sitecore.service-now.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001328) to resolve another issue as per Sitecore recommendation. Just to clarify, I have verified the "Read" access. Before this patch, one with custom role was able to just view the "Details" without locking the item. I have already raised a ticket with Sitecore support but it is getting long time to get a response. So just checking here, whether someone knows a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

In Sitecore, when you assign access rights to items, they always inherit the access right that is assigned to their parent item in the content tree. However, if you need to, you can overrule the inherited rights on an item by assigning access rights specifically on the item or denying the item the right to inherit.

Further details are available on : https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/assigning-access-rights.html

Also, you can view permission for items and you can troubleshoot permission applied to the item by adjusting the applied permission on the right side in the Access Viewer window.
[image]